# Has anyone used Arduino Fio with an MPU 6050?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, dmp, mpu

I am having trouble using the MPU 6050 DMP with my Arduino Fio. I have been using the code provided by https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050 and I am having a really tricky time getting it to work appropriately. My biggest problem is for some reason it won't recognize certain libraries, does anyone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

the board works at 3.3V, this mean its clock is only 8MHz and not the "calssic" 16MHz. Some (bad) libraries does not take account for that, and breaks.

but for what i can see, that library is fine, you have to have the https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/I2Cdev (base lib for i2c) and the one posted by you.